# locking tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

After using this : `lock tables table_name READ ;` mysql doesn't allow me to read from other tables,saying : table 'other_table' was not locked with LOCK TABLES , can someone please explain what happens actually when you lock a Table with the READ option ...

Comment: You can start by reading the documentation.

Comment: i did , but that was not helpful enough for me , Thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MySQL Documentation - LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)

> READ [LOCAL] lock:
>
> The session that holds the lock can read the table (but not write it).
>
> Multiple sessions can acquire a READ lock for the table at the same time.
>
> Other sessions can read the table without explicitly acquiring a READ lock.
>
> The LOCAL modifier enables nonconflicting INSERT statements (concurrent       inserts) by other sessions to execute while the lock is held. (See Section 9.11.3, “Concurrent Inserts”.) However, READ LOCAL cannot be used if you are going to manipulate the database using processes external to the server while you hold the lock. For InnoDB tables, READ LOCAL is the same as READ.

From my understanding, READ locks are **session locks** that say "Hey! I am going to read from this (or these) table(s), and **ONLY** these table(s) **for this session.** However, I am NOT going to able to write to it." It is important to keep in mind that other sessions can read from the same table(s) **without** having to acquire a READ lock.

So, to answer your question, you have to **specify every table you want to read from when declaring your READ lock.** You won't be able to read any other tables while in that session. Make sure to [UNLOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) your user once finished with your session.

Comment: but why the user can't read from other tables , while he just locked one table ?

Comment: @salifkeita I updated my answer to better explain it. Let me know if you need more!

Comment: Thank you so much the last part answered my question .

Comment: Excellent! Happy to be of service.